# How does matplotlib.pyplot.plot function work with only one parameter?

Tags: matplotlib

The `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` documentation says that-
`plot(y)`           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1

So what would be the output with `y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` ans with `y=[2,4,6,8,10]`?
I plotted them but was not able to infer anything. Please Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assume that `plt.plot(y)` is equivalent to `plt.plot(range(len(y)), y)`. Meaning, the first entry in `y` is plotted at `x=0`, the second at `x=1`, etc until the last, at `x=N-1` (where `N=len(y)`).

This means in the case `y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, you plot

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

In the case of `y=[2,4,6,8,10]`, it'll be

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [2,4,6,8,10]
plt.plot(x,y)
```